# MRTK eye tracking layer mask

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I want to prevent the eye tracking ray from seeing some objects, how can I do that?
This object must contain a collider and must be interactable. So I can't delete the collider component.

I think I can solve the problem by editing the layermask property of the pointer that belongs to eye tracking, but I couldn't find how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new layer named "Ignore Raycast" and assign the layer to the GameObjects which block the ray. And then, make sure the Ignore Raycast layer has been unchecked in the array of LayerMask under the [Pointing Raycast Layer Masks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/pointers?view=mrtkunity-2021-05#pointer-configuration) property in the Pointer profile.
For more information about Unity Layer please see: [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html)

Comment: With this method, eye tracking works, but I cannot select the object because raycast does not see the object. So the onclick method that I assigned to the object does not work.

Comment: So, you want the eye-tracking pointer to run through the game object, but still be able to interact with it by the pointer?

Comment: Yes, I want the eye tracking ray to pass through the object, but I also need to be able to click on the object.